# Is there some way to applyComponentOrientation automatically?

Tags: java, swing, right-to-left

If I want to flip the text to the appropriate orientation for the default locale, I can call `applyComponentOrientation` and it will walk the component tree *one time only* and set the orientations correctly.

The problem is, it really does only do it once. So if you have a GUI where components are dynamically added to the tree, these dynamically-added components come with the wrong orientation.

Here's a quick, contrived demonstration program:

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class OrientationTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Deliberately set locale to one with RTL orientation.
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ar", "SA"));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new OrientationTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test program");
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.add(makePanel());

        frame.applyComponentOrientation(
            ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(Locale.getDefault()));

        // usually dynamically added later:
        contentPane.add(makePanel());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel makePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        panel.add(new JLabel("First"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Second"));
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Even if it didn't have the above issue, I would still have to manually add it to every single frame and dialog in our application. This is impractical not only because there are a lot of dialogs, but also because not every developer on the team will be thinking about this sort of thing when they create new dialogs. Even if I somehow introduced a `FixedJDialog` class which did it properly, there is no guarantee that everyone would use it.

It's also a bit silly, because the `ComponentUI` for each component is set automatically for every component on construction without me having to do anything, so you's think that orientation could just use the same mechanism.

This got me thinking about one possible way to make this happen automatically - write multiple custom LAFs, each subclassing some other actual look and feel. On installDefaults(), set the component orientation and then delegate to the real UI.

Unfortunately, there are a lot of UI classes for each LAF and not all of them fit into a tidy system which allows for delegation. Plus, in some cases, using non-standard LAFs triggers subtle bugs in libraries which use checks on the UI class name to determine what style to paint their own stuff. So this approach isn't very appealing.

Is there a better way to do this?

*Edit:*

I have a solution for the stuff inside a single dialog now.

```
    ContainerListener listener = new ContainerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
            e.getChild().applyComponentOrientation(
                e.getContainer().getComponentOrientation());
            addListenersToTree(e.getChild());
        }
    };
    addListenersToTree(frame);
```

`addListenersToTree` just recurses the hierarchy, adding the listener everywhere. It's a dirty solution and I don't know what the memory cost is of having all these additional listeners, but it works for one dialog so it solves some fraction of the issue at least.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the component orientation to the inner most `JPanel`.

Solution 1

```
private JPanel makePanel() {
    FlowLayout flowLayout = null;
    if (ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(Locale.getDefault()).isLeftToRight()) {
        flowLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    } else {
        flowLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
    }
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(flowLayout);
    ...
}
```

Solution 2

```
private JPanel makePanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    panel.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(Locale.getDefault()));
    ...
}
```

---

This also works if component is added later after applying component orientation.

```
private JPanel makePanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    panel.add(new JLabel("First"));
    panel.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(Locale.getDefault()));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Second"));
    return panel;
}
```

Have a look at [How to Use FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)

Comment: As stated in the question: "This is impractical not only because there are a lot of dialogs, but also because not every developer on the team will be thinking about this sort of thing when they create new dialogs." Well, I know I can solve panels by adding listeners for new panels appearing anyway. That may be enough to solve the issue within a single dialog. Then the problem is back to "but we still have a lot of dialogs."

Comment: Also that second label is in the wrong orientation anyway. Try adding an icon to it and set its alignment to `SwingConstants.LEADING` and you'll see that even though Second is to the left of First, its icon is to the left of the text, which doesn't match the orientation specified.

Comment: Why don't you create a custom class for this type of behavior and replace `new FlowLayout()` with `new MyFlowLayout()` for e.g. `class MyFlowLayout extends FlowLayout{public MyFlowLayout(){//orientation based code goes here}}`

Comment: Do the same type of customization for Dialog as well. It's good design of keeping common code at one place.

Comment: Replacing the layouts throughout the application would be an easy one-off but it would break all the GUI builder forms and and new forms people made would be using the normal layout again. I'd have to hack up NetBeans to make it use our customised layouts...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue (and found this question) while testing [HVLayout](https://github.com/fwi/HVLayout) and I did not find a fully automatic solution for the problem, but maybe the partial manual solution can help (somebody).

When you dynamically add/remove components, you have to inform Swing to update the UI if you add a component that does it's own rendering like `JScrollPane` and that is done via a combination of `revalidate()` / `repaint()` (or even `pack()` in a dialog). Within this "update UI" procedure the `applyComponentOrientation(..)` method can be called with the component orientation of the parent/root container.

This does not solve the problem for all current dialogs and if there is no common/shared utility method for updating the UI after adding/removing components then it will probably never work.

But, as @Braj found, all this has little effect when layout managers are configured to use absolute positions (e.g. `LEFT` instead of `LEADING`). Avoid layout managers that do not use relative positions.

For the details of the manual solution, you can look at the [test UI source code](https://github.com/fwi/HVLayout/blob/master/swing-demo/src/main/java/nl/fw/swing/demo/HvlayoutTestUI.java) (search for "buildTextScrollerCheckBox").

Comment: The code there is interesting because it calls recursively, but applyComponentOrientation is already recursive... As far as your point about having to call revalidate(), that is actually incorrect. If you add your component via the normal means, Swing will already call these for you (I once verified this in the debugger, because I wasn't sure myself.) But if you have a component which is doing its own rendering, you have to call revalidate(), repaint() and the like. Or if you are adding a component to a dialog, you might have to pack() that.

Comment: @Trejkaz Did some more testing and found the errors you pointed out (thanks for that - bad oversight on my part). I updated the answer, of which I'm not sure it is an answer anymore ...